# Get list of unpaired Bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-bluetooth

How to get(scan) list of unpaired Bluetooth devices in android? meaning have to scan nearby devices. Would you please help in this regard.

I know how to find(scan) paired devices and do all things(socket, connection, server, communication etc) with pared devices but unable to find(scan) nearby Bluetooth devices programmatically. I hope you people will understand my problem and help accordingly.

I want to scan for list of unpaired Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices#discover-devices

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, The problem was with device as well and still (the problem comes rarely) but code is working fine now for my devices as well. There may be delay in scanning some devices. i.e. 3 devices scanned with no time and other one or two devices take time to scan. Some time broadcast receiver missed to invoke, that's why time to get an end.

Following is the broadcast receiver which will return Bluetooth device.

```
class FoundDeviceReceiver(
    private val onDeviceFound: (BluetoothDevice) -> Unit
): BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    when(intent?.action) {
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
            val device = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE,
                    BluetoothDevice::class.java
                )
            } else {
                intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            }
            device?.let(onDeviceFound)
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the method to register broadcast receiver and start discovery. We also have to unregister the broadcast receiver according to our requirements.

```
override fun startDiscovery() {
        if (!hasPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)) {
            return
        }

    context.registerReceiver(
        foundDeviceReceiver, IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
    )


    bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
}
```

`bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()` is the build in method, which will invoke the registered broadcast receiver and we will successfully receive Bluetooth devices.

If someone will have still problem then he can comment, I will be happy to respond.